# Visualforce: Checkbox is not firing function onclick

Tags: visualforce, javascript, inputcheckboxes, onclick, checkbox

I've tried everything I can think of to get this checkbox to work. This code is just supposed to trigger a function when a checkbox is checked. It currently does not trigger the alert, it only "visually" checks. Thank you for any input.

```
<apex:page >
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checked() {
        alert("This has been triggered");
    }
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputcheckbox onclick="checked()"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is reported in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: checked is not a function

It seems to be a name conflict but I can't see where.

Changing the function name to e.g. `isChecked` works around the problem.

**PS**

The fix that relates to the root cause is this:

```
<apex:inputcheckbox onclick="window.checked()"/>
```

that references the global function `checked` that is otherwise shadowed (hidden) by the `checked` property of the input checkbox element.

Comment: I should have included the error message. I didn't think renaming would work... still it's probably not a great pattern to follow. That's a quick and dirty workaround though.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I disagree that there is anything dirty or workaround about it and would argue its a great pattern to follow unless a more complicated solution pays back in some way.

Comment: I would argue that unobtrusive listeners are a lot less vulnerable to API changes and naming conflicts. Leaking functions into the global state is not just a code smell, it can have harmful side-effects as demonstrated by this very question. What if a naming conflict *also* gets introduced that breaks `isChecked`?

Comment: I guess here it was not a `Javascript` conflict, but I still think that naming functions that do not need to be named and leaking them into the global state is an avoidable smell.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yep thats an argument for the complexity. Caused me to Google a bit and find [what is the difference between overengineering, underengineering and rightengineering?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/288146/what-is-the-difference-between-overengineering-underengineering-and-rightengine).

Comment: Yes, but it's purely a matter of perspective whether `window.checked` is under-engineered or unobtrusive listeners are over-engineered. The unobtrusive concept has been around for many years now and is not difficult to implement. If you gave zero care to best practices and use jQuery, it only takes two more lines than the original solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, makes a lot of sense. Definitely saved me hours of more confusion!

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you should always do when you face a `Javascript` error is open up the console. Here's how to do it on:

- [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en)
- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console)
- [Opera](https://help.revaxarts.com/how-can-i-open-the-browsers-console/)
- [Safari](https://www.wickedlysmart.com/hfjsconsole/)
- [IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you had done so, you would have seen the following error when you click the checkbox:

> Uncaught TypeError: checked is not a function

There are a few ways to deal with this. My preference is to use **unobtrusive listeners**. Try this vanilla `Javascript`:

```
<apex:page >
    <script>
    (function (D) {
        "use strict";
        D.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var i, checkboxes = D.querySelectorAll('input.myClass');
            for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                    alert('fire');
                });
            }
        }); 
    })(document);
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputcheckbox styleClass="myClass" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Or its `jQuery` equivalent:

```
<apex:page >
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function ($) {
        "use strict";
        $(function () {
            $('input.myClass').click(function () {
                alert('fire');
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputcheckbox styleClass="myClass" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @AerinC A vital tool for any Javascript development!